# Mongodb Error sizeStorer.wt No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm totally new at Mongo, so I've installed (using a Mac with OS x El Capitan v 10.11.2). I'm writing a new `Node` app and for now, I've included the DB folder within the app folder. The first time I ran mongo using `mongod --dbpath MYPATH` it worked perfectly (no extra options). I usually close it using `cmd C` keys, so it closes fine.

The problem is that every time I restart working on the project (after a few days, restarting my laptop), I always get this problem (attached a small piece of the stacktrace:

`2016-06-22T22:44:09.024-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/Users/despino/xxxxx/project/data" } }
2016-06-22T22:44:09.024-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /Users/despino/xxxxx/project/data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-06-22T22:44:09.025-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=9G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-06-22T22:44:09.811-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (2) [1466660649:811376][8324:0x7fff77722000], file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /Users/despino/xxxxx/project/data/sizeStorer.wt: No such file or directory
2016-06-22T22:44:09.811-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (2) [1466660649:811715][8324:0x7fff77722000], file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /Users/despino/xxxxx/project/data/sizeStorer.wt: No such file or directory
2016-06-22T22:44:09.811-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: 2: No such file or directory at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp 67`

I have different questions:
1 - How do I fix this? How do I prevent this from happening over and over? Last time I had to drop the entire folder and recreate the DB from scratch?
(BTW, I've tried to change ownership on files, remove locks manually with no success).

Here is my node info:
Node version 
5.7.1
NPM version 
3.6.0
Mongo Version
3.2.4

BTW, the binaries for mongo were installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/` not sure if this is affecting somehow.

Thanks for the help

Comment: WiredTiger engine's `WiredTigerSizeStore` requires file: `sizeStorer.wt` , which it can't find. Did you delete this file ?

Comment: No... I did not deleted it... basically when I run `mongod --dbpath` I'm supposing it will create all the files required right?... Is there any reason why is this not being created on my db path? Thanks @S.D.

Comment: It is not creating all files anew because: `Detected data files in....` . It has found existing files and is tying to restore the state.

Comment: Yes, that I get it... but why is the file not there? Why was it deleted if I'm closing the mongo connection using a `ctrl c` command?. I don't expect to have to recreate or empty the folder every time I start the application... BTW, that happens just if after I add some data to the collections... next time I've try to start working on the project and reopen `mongodb` i get this errors.